# visual studio End of Statement expected

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am getting the below error in my SSRS visual studio reports.

> contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

But I cannot see what I need to change.

The code I am using is:-

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued")),0,(Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued")) + (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1"))/(Sum(Fields!PAFQuantity.Value, "ForecastHrs")
))))
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 extra closing parens.

When you have code in an expression or in the SSRS code box and it won't compile, try creating a VB.Net project in Visual Studio and pasting the code into a real code editor. The keyword highlighting and inline syntax checking can help immensely.